# How to set shipping costs for a non-US website using Paypal Website Payments Standard

Tags: web, paypal, standards, payment

I am making my first e-commerce website and it is only basic and low volume. I've used Paypal Website Payments Standard with the cart upload function to integrate with Paypal. One problem though, I cannot provide a shipping estimate until the user enters their address in Paypal and I cannot see a facility to do some kind of callback to my site for the appropriate shipping cost based on country without using Paypal Express Checkout. The shipping cost can only be specified by the cost of the items within the Merchant profile on Paypal and my customer only wants there to be one price for within NZ, one within Australia and another for all other countries.

Any tips? Or is Paypal Express the only way without obtaining address information of the user before uploading the cart to Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Express is the minimum product to get you a callback facility for shipping. Nothing similar available with Payments Standard.

Since you only have the three zones, You might solicit and present with a dropdown without requiring the full adddress... then validity check in the IPN handler to hold the order if they are in France and have selected NZ domestic.